# React: how to redirect some pages to a login page

Tags: reactjs

I'm moving my first steps in react world and I'm stuck with a problem with authentication.
I prepared a login page that is presented to the user when a token is empty. The page call a login web api (.netcore backend). When return the token the homepage is rendered. But if I want to present the homepage to all and only some page authenticated, I'm not able to resolve this problem.

My App.js file

```
function App() {
    const { token, setToken } = useToken();

      if (!token) {
          return <Login setToken={setToken} />
      }
 
    return (
        <Layout>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
            <Route path='/counter' component={Counter} />
            <Route path='/fetch-data' component={FetchData} />
            <Route path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
            <Route path='/settings' component={Settings} />
        </Layout>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Where I have to move the Login component to authenticate Settings page (for example)?
Thank you!

**Update**
Thank you for answers, now I implemented Private and Public Route.
Now my App.js is as follow

> ```
> return (
>     <Layout>
>         <BrowserRouter>
>             <Switch>
>                 <PublicRoute restricted={false} component={Home} path="/" exact />
>                 <PublicRoute restricted={true} component={Login} path="/signin" exact />
>                 <PrivateRoute component={Dashboard} path="/dashboard" exact />
>             </Switch>
>         </BrowserRouter>
>     </Layout>
> ```

Layout is a component that display a NavMenu and a Container

```
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <NavMenu />
        <Container>
          {this.props.children}
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

and NavMenu ha the links
...

```
<ul className="navbar-nav flex-grow">
                <NavItem>
                  <NavLink tag={Link} className="text-dark" exact to="/">Home</NavLink>
                </NavItem>
                <NavItem>
                  <NavLink tag={Link} className="text-dark" exact to="/dashboard">Dashboard</NavLink>
                </NavItem>
                <NavItem>
                  <NavLink tag={Link} className="text-dark" exact to="/signin">Signin</NavLink>
                </NavItem>
              </ul>
```

...

When I click on a link in the Navbar nothing happens. In the url appear the destination link but browser doesn't load it. I need to press return to go to the page. I cannon unserstand why...
Can you help?
Thanks

Comment: You need to set up a "PrivateRoute" that can handle checking the token against the api and then allowing you to go to that route.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a privateRoute component, you can check this [one](https://github.com/MohamedWSalah/WouldYouRather-UdacityNanoDegree/blob/master/src/components/PrivateRoute.jsx)

```
<Route
  {...rest}
  render={({ location }) => {
    return loggedUser !== "" ? (
      children
    ) : (
      <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/login", state: { from: location } }} />
    );
  }}
/>
```

so any component wrapped in `privateRoute` component will have to go through it and check if the userLogged is empty or not, in your case you will change it to fit your API call.

then on your `app.js` you will need to wrap them up using `privateRoute`

```
<Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/login">
        <Login />
      </Route>

      <PrivateRoute exact path="/">
        <Home />
      </PrivateRoute>

      <PrivateRoute exact path="/counter">
        <counter/>
      </PrivateRoute>

      <PrivateRoute exact path="/fetch-data">
        <FetchData/>
      </PrivateRoute>

      <PrivateRoute exact path="/dashboard">
        <Dashboard/>
      </PrivateRoute>

      <PrivateRoute exact path="/settings">
        <Settings/>
      </PrivateRoute>

      <PrivateRoute path="">
        <NotFound />
      </PrivateRoute>
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

Now all those components in the PrivateRoute, will redirect to the Login page unless the condition inside the PrivateRoute is fulfilled.